# Utilizar vírgula no input com Bootstrap Touchspin

Tags: javascript, input

Estou utilizando o Bootstrap Toutchspin para montar um input,

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

 <div class="form-group">
   <input type="text" id="P8473_QTDE" name="p_t05" value="0" size="25" onkeypress="return submitEnter(this,event)" class="mt10 form-control">
 </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-touchspin/4.2.5/jquery.bootstrap-touchspin.min.js"></script>

<script>
$("input[name='p_t05']").TouchSpin({
  min: 0,
  max: 1000,
  boostat: 5,
  decimals: 3,
  forcestepdivisibility: "none",
  step: 1,
  maxboostedstep: 10,
  buttondown_class: "btn btn-ciano btn-lg btn-mob",
  buttonup_class: "btn btn-ciano btn-lg btn-mob",
  mousewheel: "true",
  initval: 0
});
</script>
```

Até aqui maravilha, 
porém preciso que o input utilize vírgula ao invés do ponto.

Comment: No lugar do ponto?

Comment: isso mesmo, desculpe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se quiser trocar o ponto pela vírgula, você pode fazer um replace no `value` do input. Basta usar os eventos `change touchspin.on.min touchspin.on.stopspin` e substituir um pelo outro:

```js
$("input[name='p_t05']").TouchSpin({
  min: 0,
  max: 1000,
  boostat: 5,
  decimals: 3,
  forcestepdivisibility: "none",
  step: 1,
  maxboostedstep: 10,
  buttondown_class: "btn btn-ciano btn-lg btn-mob",
  buttonup_class: "btn btn-ciano btn-lg btn-mob",
  mousewheel: "true",
  initval: 0
}).on("change touchspin.on.min touchspin.on.stopspin", function(){
   var t = this;
   t.value = t.value.replace(/\./g, ",");
}).trigger("change");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-touchspin/4.2.5/jquery.bootstrap-touchspin.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
   <input type="text" id="P8473_QTDE" name="p_t05" value="0" size="25" onkeypress="return submitEnter(this,event)" class="mt10 form-control">
</div>
```

Comment: Muito grato!! funcionou.

Comment: Quando altera o valor após a vírgula, o campo perde a referência.

Comment: Como assim?....

Comment: ao informar 1,250 por exemplo, e sair do input o campo perde a referência da fração e está sendo arredondado para 1.

Comment: Entendi. É só vc voltar o ponto quando for tratar o número no calculo. Só mudar os sinais no replace

Comment: Na hora de tratar o valor como número, vc vai fazer assim: `parseFloat($("input[name='p_t05']").val().replace(",", "."))`